Fluid for Tailwind doesn't get installed in my project
I' starting a new project using React+Vite+TS and Tailwind. I was curious to try fluid for Tailwind here but it doesn't work.
I keep getting this warn message:
warn - fluid-tailwind: Fluid extractor not found in your Tailwind config
This is my tailwing.config.js file:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const fluidTailwind = require("fluid-tailwind");

module.exports = {
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: "#daff6f",
        secondary: "#a8aeff",
        tertiary: "#e6e6fa",
        black: "#161616",
        subtext: "#d3d3d3",
        secondSubtext: "#717171",
        secondaryAccent: "#CDD0ED",
        primaryAccent: "#EFFFC3",
      },
      screens: {
        xsm: { max: "650px" },
        md: { min: "651px" },
        lg: { min: "768px", max: "1023px" },
        xl: { min: "1024px", max: "1279px" },
        "2xl": { min: "1280px", max: "1535px" },
        "3xl": { min: "1536px" },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    fluidTailwind({
      textSizes: {
        sm: "14px",
        base: "16px",
        lg: "18px",
        xl: "20px",
      },
    }),
  ],
};


I tried to import "extract" and added it in "content" first, then "plugins" but it doesn't work or it gives me an error.
does anyone know how to make it work?
Thank you
